# Pangrams CodeEval challenge

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge

I took a challenge on [CodeEval](http://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/37/). Although the code seems to work for the examples taken from the site, I feel it is not really pretty and must be more complicated than it should be.

> **Description:**
>
> The sentence 'A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' contains
>   every single letter in the alphabet. Such sentences are called
>   pangrams. You are to write a program, which takes a sentence, and
>   returns all the letters it is missing (which prevent it from being a
>   pangram). You should ignore the case of the letters in sentence, and
>   your return should be all lower case letters, in alphabetical order.
>   You should also ignore all non US-ASCII characters.In case the input
>   sentence is already a pangram, print out the string NULL.

```
import sys
filepath = sys.argv[1]
f = open(filepath)
wholealphabet = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
                 's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
for line in f:
    sortedletters = list(set(line.lower()))
    i = 0
    while i != len(sortedletters):
        if wholealphabet.count(sortedletters[i]) != 0: 
            i = i + 1
        else:
            sortedletters.pop(i)
    missingletters = ""
    for letter in wholealphabet:
        if sortedletters.count(letter) == 0:
            missingletters +=letter
    if len(missingletters) == 0:
        print("NULL")
    else:
        print(missingletters)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of Python's greatest strengths is its built-in capability to use sets directly. I don't feel you've used sets to their fullest extent here. I'd also like to point out the `with` statement, which you should probably use to handle file handles.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import sys
from string import ascii_lowercase
filepath = sys.argv[1]
wholealphabet = frozenset(ascii_lowercase)

# Use with to handle file … handles
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f: # assume a line is a sentence, not exactly per spec?
        # sortedletters = list(set(line.lower())) # guaranteed to be *unsorted*
        missingletters = wholealphabet.difference(line.lower())
        if missingletters:
            print ''.join(sorted(missingletters))
        else:
            print 'NULL'
```

That's really all you need. Unless you want to reconsider the definition of a sentence. :)

Comment: wow it really is much simpler that way, didn't know about the with. It seems to work like the using statement in c#. I will do a research on each of the method used as I do not know them. I indeed forgot about actually doing the sort, I made some attempt with the interpreter at first and then pretty much copy pasted in a .py file. What did you mean about reconsidering the definition of a sentence? Wish I could upvote but I do not have the required rank yet. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind about the sentence definition I rereaded the answer and understood :)

Comment: FYI I moved the `from future…` to the top of the code, because (as I'm sure you've discovered) the code won't work otherwise.

Comment: Indeed I had to change it, I also discover that string has a ascii_lowercase method which I used instead of letters.lower()

Comment: Great catch. So edited!

Answer (score 6):

```
import sys
filepath = sys.argv[1]
f = open(filepath)
```

I recommend not using one letter variable names (usually). They make the code hard to read.

```
wholealphabet = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
                 's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
```

I'd have made this a string

```
wholealphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Shorter and works pretty much the same

```
for line in f:
    sortedletters = list(set(line.lower()))
```

Yeah, that's not sorted.

```
    i = 0
    while i != len(sortedletters):
        if wholealphabet.count(sortedletters[i]) != 0:
```

This is the same as `sortedletters[i] in wholealphabet`, which is clearer.

```
            i = i + 1
        else:
            sortedletters.pop(i)
```

Modifying a list while iterating over it is bound to be confusing. Its hard to see what you are doing here. The best way in python is usually to create a new list. Like this:

```
valid_letters = []
for letter in sortedletters:
    if letter in wholealphabet:
        valid_letters.append(letter)
```

See how much easier it is to see the result of that? In fact, you can even do it more compactly:

```
valid_letters = [letter for letter in sortedletters if letter in wholealphabet]


    missingletters = ""
```

Adding to a string can be expensive, I recommend using a list

```
    for letter in wholealphabet:
        if sortedletters.count(letter) == 0:
            missingletters +=letter
```

Again, you can simplify this using a list comphrehension

```
missingletters = [letter for letter in wholealphabet if letter not in sortedletters]


    if len(missingletters) == 0:
        print("NULL")
    else:
        print(missingletters)
```

As kojrio points out, if you use sets in python you can implement this very easily. His advice to use a with statement is also good.

Comment: I agree that the string is really easier to see that the list of char. I was wondering if there wasn't already a way to test if a char is a valid letter if I had been in c++ I would have casted to a int and would have compared with the ascii table. Indeed forgot the sort that was pretty bad, didn't have enough test case to spot it. I find list comprehension to be hard to read but maybe it's just because I am not used to see it like that. I'll read about it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tommy, list comprehensions can be hard to read until you get used to them.

Comment: yes, I guess it something you get used to just like lambda expression and then start loving.